# Spectrum of right shift operator in weighted $l2$ sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $l_2(a)$ be a hilbert space defined with following inner product:
$\langle x_n,y_n\rangle = \sum a^k x_k y_k$. (It's a weighted sequence space with the weights  $\omega_i = a^i$).
It's elements are the sequences for which the norm is defined and finite. ( $\langle x_n,x_n \rangle = c ).$

The left and right shift operators are defined as usual: $S_r(({x_0 , x_1, x_2, ... x_n , ...})) = (0, x_0, ...)$ 
$S_l(({x_0 , x_1, x_2, ... x_n , ...})) = (x_1, x_2, ...)$

Now, I was asked to find $\sigma(S_r), \sigma(S_l)$. My attempt was this:
I found the operator norm of both operators. $\lvert S_r\rvert = a$, $\lvert S_l\rvert = 1/a$.

Then, I figured that $S_l$ has eigenvalues for every $\lambda$ satisfying $\lvert \lambda \rvert < 1/a$. Because the specturm is closed and bounded by the operator norm, i figured that $\sigma(S_l)$ is the closed ball with radius $1/a$.

Additionaly, i found that $S_r ^ * = aS_l$, and therefore $Im(S_r - \lambda I)^\bot = Ker(aS_l - \bar{\lambda} I) = Ker(a(S_l - (\bar{\lambda}/a) I)) = Ker(S_l - (\bar{\lambda} / a) I) \neq 0 \Longleftrightarrow \bar{\lambda} / a < 1/a$.

So i deduced that if $\lvert\lambda\rvert < 1$ so $\lambda \in \sigma(S_r)$. which doesn't make sense to me if $a < 1$ and then the spectrum has to be bounded by $\lvert S_r \rvert = a$.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a natural map $U : \ell^2_{a}\rightarrow \ell^2$ given by
$$
             U(x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots) = (a^{0/2}x_0,a^{1/2}x_1,a^{2/2}x_2,a^{3/2}x_3,\cdots)
$$
$U$ is a unitary map between the two Hilbert spaces. If $S_a$ is the shift operator on $\ell^2_a$, then $S_a$ may be pulled back to $\ell^2$ by looking at $T : \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ defined by
$$
                  T = US_aU^{-1},
$$
which is described by
\begin{align}
   (x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots) & \mapsto (x_0,a^{-1/2}x_1,a^{-2/2}x_2,\cdots) \\
       & \mapsto (0,x_0,a^{-1/2}x_1,a^{-2/2}x_2,\cdots) \\
       & \mapsto (0,a^{1/2}x_0,a^{2/2}a^{-1/2}x_1,a^{3/2}a^{-2/2}x_2,\cdots) \\
       &  = \sqrt{a}(0,x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots).
\end{align}
That is, $T=\sqrt{a}S$, where $S$ is the ordinary shift operator on $\ell^2$.